# I have a python brute force password cracking code, my problem is, how do I use it to hack my own wifi

Tags: passwords, cracking

So I have the code, I'm just wondering how I can use it to crack passwords, I set a password and the code tries all possibilities and it works. Im just wondering how to use it to crack passwords. do I run a script that automatically copy and pastes the passwords, do I use system 32.

pls be nice to me, just learning :p

Comment: You have to write code in Python to connect to wifi, e.g. https://pypi.org/project/python-wifi/

Comment: is it a winrar file?

Comment: I think you should learn how to write code in Python and how to libraries. Then start cracking wifi